# ILMerge and cross references

Tags: c#, .net, ilmerge

this question is relate to ILMerge and how to handle some specific case I'm facing.
The issue is relevant for a bigger project, with many DLLs, but it is simple to summarize with a example:

The project has some files:
MultiDLLPrj.exe
DLL1.dll
DLL2.dll
DLL3.dll

MultiDLLPrj.exe has references to all of the other DLLs.
DLL3 has a reference to DLL2.

Using ILMerge, my target is to merge MultiDLLPrj.exe + DLL1.dll + DLL2.dll, leaving out DLL3.dll.

Here comes the issue: ILMerge megres the give assemblies correctly, leaves out correctly DLL3.dll, which is
copied in the same folder as the merged MultiDLLPrj.exe, but the proces execution is broken by the fact that DLL3.dll,
when loaded, can't fine DLL2.dll (it has been merged in MultiDLLPrj.exe).

The command line used is:
.\ILMerge.exe /lib:.\ /targetplatform:v4,C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319 /log /out:.\bin\output.exe MultiDLLPrj.exe .\DLL1.dll .\DLL2.dll /target:exe

Now, apart from the obvious issue of the corss-reference, is there any way to make this to work, or the basic "design" is simply
incompatible with the ILmerge approach?

Comment: Does it work if you leave DLL2 in the folder? Or do you get runtime errors (e.g. about duplicate types) in that case?

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Just did the test. In this case it works, I suppose that DLL3 uses the external copy of the DLL2.dll though, which kid of defeat the main idea of merging the assemblies in the first place

Comment: True, obviously. However is there a reason why you don't want to also merge DLL3?

Comment: In the real case, some DLLs handle serializations and when merged in, the process of loading old data fails. We resorted to leave out the DLLs that nadle serialization, but currently we are facing that issue...